# update created by (ownerid) and last modified by in apex

Tags: apex

I have created an integration user account. How can I update the created by and last updated by fields with the details of this integration user while doing a bulk dml insert in apex? Right now its showing the logged in users name when the apex class is run.

```
// records to be updated received from json
jsonBody = '[{"count__c":"445", "downloads__c":"340"}, {"count__c":"440", "downloads__c":"240"}]';

List<Data__c> dList = (List<Data__c>) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonBody, List<Data__c>.class);

countList has unique count__c values, say: 445,440 // to use in the IN clause.

// Querry parent for those plan ids in daily data json
List<Parent__c> parentList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Parent__c 
    WHERE count__c IN :countList];

List<Data__c> dataToInsert = new List<Data__c>();

// Loop through dList - inner loop
for(Data__c dRecords : dList) {
     for(Parent__c parentRecords : parentList) {         
          if(dRecords.count__c  == parentRecords.count__c) {
                dRecords.downloads__c  = parentRecords.downloads__c ;
                dataToInsert.add(dRecords );
           }
      } 
} 
insert dataToInsert;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to update those fields?

Comment: Just updated the deserializing line in the original code above. Right now I am not updating the owner id, so its displaying the logged in users name in the inserted records when the apex is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior: your audit fields are always going to show the current context user*.

If you want your integration user to be the context user for these changes, you need to run the Apex class as your integration user. That might mean:

- Authenticating a remote system calling the API as the integration user.
- Scheduling a Scheduled Apex class while logged in as the integration user.
- Doing a one-off test of an Apex class while logged in as the integration user.

The user is not a property of your Apex class itself, but the context in which it is running.

* Unless you have the org settings configured to allow you to set audit fields via the API and do so as part of a data load.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do this only on insert, the below approach works only while inserting records not on update.

The `CreatedBy` and `LastModifiedBy` fields are audit fields, You would need to assign the users `Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation` permission for them to be able to set a Desired user to these fields. Once these permission is assigned to the users who run this class. In your apex class you can dynamically assign the desired Id to these fields. Kindly refer the below URLs for more info

```
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331038&type=1

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kEwQIAU
```